# Access a particular part of string is a line

Tags: bash, shell, sed, grep, cut

The content of my file: file.conf is

```
sm key mappings
sm_key_7_value_0="/www/cgi-bin/scripts/app_web_mood_control.sh Global masteron;echo hello"
sm_key_7_value_1="/www/cgi-bin/scripts/app_web_mood_control.sh Global masteroff"
sm_key_8_value_0="/www/cgi-bin/scripts/app_web_mood_control.sh Global green"
sm_key_8_value_1="/www/cgi-bin/scripts/app_web_mood_control.sh Global away"
sm_key_9_value_0="/www/cgi-bin/scripts/app_usr_core_sendPulse.sh CR_D601 C1_OPN"
sm_key_9_value_1="/www/cgi-bin/scripts/app_usr_core_sendPulse.sh CR_D601 C1_CLS"
sm_key_A_value_0="/www/cgi-bin/scripts/app_oasis_irControl.sh IR_D03 AC_ON_"
sm_key_A_value_1="/www/cgi-bin/scripts/app_oasis_irControl.sh IR_D03 AC_OFF"
sm_key_B_value_0="/www/cgi-bin/scripts/app_usr_core_sendInstruction.sh CR_D601 OP_01N"
sm_key_B_value_1="/www/cgi-bin/scripts/app_usr_core_sendInstruction.sh CR_D601 OP_01F"
sm_key_C_value_0="/www/cgi-bin/scripts/app_usr_core_sendInstruction.sh CR_D601 OP_02N"
sm_key_C_value_1="echo 123 && $(sleep 5) && $(echo hello)"
```

I have used grep

```
 grep "/www/cgi-bin/scripts/app_web_mood_control.sh" file.conf
```

The output of grep is

```
sm_key_7_value_0="/www/cgi-bin/scripts/app_web_mood_control.sh Global masteron;echo hello"
sm_key_7_value_1="/www/cgi-bin/scripts/app_web_mood_control.sh Global masteroff"
sm_key_8_value_0="/www/cgi-bin/scripts/app_web_mood_control.sh Global green"
sm_key_8_value_1="/www/cgi-bin/scripts/app_web_mood_control.sh Global away"
```

In this o/p of grep i needed to access  `global masteron` `Global masteroff` `Global green` `Global away` and put it in a variable. Aim is i want to access the anything which is after control.sh and store it in a variable how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

Something to get you started:

```
$ awk -F'[ ;"]' -f g.awk your_input
Global masteron
Global masteroff
Global green
Global away
```

where

```
$ cat g.awk
/Global/ {
    print $3, $4
}
```

Variable:

```
$ a=$(awk -F'[ ;"]' -f g.awk your_input)

$ echo $a
Global masteron Global masteroff Global green Global away
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var=$(grep -Po '(?<=/www/cgi-bin/scripts/app_web_mood_control\.sh )[^;"]*' file.conf)
```

test:

```
kent$  a=$(grep -Po '(?<=/www/cgi-bin/scripts/app_web_mood_control\.sh )[^;"]*' f)

kent$  echo $a
Global masteron
Global masteroff
Global green
Global away
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `readarray` and `sed`:

```
#!/bin/bash

FILE='file.conf'

# Get values.
readarray -t MATCHES < <(sed -n '/app_web_mood_control.sh/{ s|.*app_web_mood_control.sh ||; s|;.*$||; s|\"||; p; }' "$FILE")

# Demonstrate the values.
for A in "${MATCHES[@]}"; do
    echo "$A"
done
```

Example output:

```
Global masteron
Global masteroff
Global green
Global away
```

All values saved in array `MATCHES` starts from index 0 so you could access them by `${MATCHES[0]}`, `${MATCHES[1]}`, and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Using `\K` in `grep`:

```
readarray -t found < <( grep -P -o '/www/cgi-bin/scripts/app_web_mood_control.sh \K[^;"]*' file.conf)

for curFound in "${found[@]}"; do
    echo "$curFound"
done
```

Output:

> Global masteron
>   Global masteroff
>   Global green
>   Global away